# How to create a type function that checks whether a type is empty object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type function `IsEmpty` such that:

```
type a = IsEmpty<{}> // true
type b = IsEmpty<{x: 1}> // never
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
type IsEmpty<T> = {} extends T ? true : never;
```

see [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)